How to write Laravel feature test for streamed content to browser?
I could use some help writing a feature test for a route that returns streamed content. Here's the details...
I have a Laravel route:
Route::get('/export/user/role/{role}', [Admin\ExportUserController::class, 'export'])->name('export.user');

that will call the export controller method below. The export() method gets a collection of users from the database and streams rows of users in '.csv' format to the browser.
Here's the export method:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Enums\RoleEnum;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Spatie\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcelWriter;

class ExportUserController extends Controller
{
    public function export(RoleEnum $role)
    {
        $filename = strtolower($role->value) . '.csv';
        $filetype = 'csv';

        $writer = SimpleExcelWriter::streamDownload($filename, $filetype);

        // First row is column labels.
        $writer->addHeader([
            'Company Name',
            'Account Code',
            'First Name',
            'Last Name',
            'Email',
            'Registration',
            'Email Verified',
            'Last Login',
            'Status',
            'Role'
        ]);

        User::where('role', '=', $role->value)
            ->orderby('first_name', 'asc')
            ->orderby('last_name', 'asc')
            ->chunk(
                200, // Chunk size is arbitrary, but reasonable.
                function($users) use ($writer) {
                    foreach($users as $user) {
                        $writer->addRow(
                            [
                                $user->company_name,
                                $user->account_code,
                                $user->first_name,
                                $user->last_name,
                                $user->email,
                                $user->local_created_at_date,
                                $user->local_email_verified_at_date,
                                $user->local_last_login_at_date,
                                $user->status->value,
                                $user->role->value,
                            ]
                        );
                    }

                    flush(); // Flush the buffer every chunk.
                }
            );

        $writer->toBrowser();
        $writer->close();
    }
}

I could use some help with writing a feature test for this route. I'm not sure what to test or how exactly to write it up. When I run the below test method, the streamed content to the browser is output to the terminal, mixed in with the artisan test output. I'm not sure if I should be capturing the streamed output and inspecting the content, etc..
Any tips on writing this test method and preventing the output to the terminal?
Thanks!
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Admin;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Enums\RoleEnum;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

/**
 * Test the 'Export Users' Feature.
 */
class UserExportTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_export_users(): void
    {
        // Create the admin performing the activity.
        $admin = User::factory()->admin()->create();

        // Populate the database with users.
        User::factory(4)->user()->create();

        // What is the correct way to write a test for streamed content?
        $response = $this
            ->actingAs($admin)
            ->get(route('admin.export.user', ['role' => RoleEnum::User->value]));

        // ...?
    }
}

I've read through the Laravel.com documentation and Googled the heck out of this, to no avail. I'm not sure where to turn. I appreciate any help.

I never had to mock or test a stream, could you share what library you are using or the code that refers to SimpleExcelWriter? I want to see method signing and stuff like that

@matiaslauriti The author, Spatie, provides a GitHub repo for this package (simple-excel). Is this what you're requesting?

Yes, that is what I was looking for, I cannot download and try it locally, I do not have enough time to setup everything, but could you add ->dump() on your test after ->get(), so we get an output of the content? I know you said it is being output to the terminal, I just want to see if we get any data on the response or not at all

I see that the main package doing this is openspout, see this file, it is hardcoding to php://output and that is the console when you run a CLI command. I am not sure then what to do, but I would start searching about php://output, Laravel, and tests, something must be available about this

I looked through the openspout code and my controller's use of it through SimpleExcelWriter::streamDownload(). I see what you mean where the output is going to stdout. I did notice that when running my phpunit test suite, phpunit abruptly stops when it hits this particular test and the download output is written to the console. My guess is that when openspout writes (or 'downloads') the content, it goes to stdout and the tests stop before the $this->get() request even returns in my test.

I found that the results of the get() request is NOT returned into the $response variable as I tried to dump the contents. The test at the point of the get() request is dying before then. As requested, here's the truncated output:

Running "php artisan test --filter export_users" in the current app container...
"Company Name","Account Code","First Name","Last Name",Email,Registration,"Email Verified","Last Login",Status,Role
"Barton and Sons",61152878,Alexanne,Dach,harrison.christiansen@example.net,2024-06-02,2024-06-02,,Active,User

I'm thinking at this point that perhaps the openspout implementation is not compatible with phpunit testing. Perhaps I'll need to abort this test, unless I'm missing something.

I understand the need of testing this part, I never had to try to go over or circumvent phpoutput, so I honestly have no idea how to solve it (and you still test). I will sadly not be able of help here, I would say that you can just not test this part and done, but would be awesome to do so

Thank you for all your time on this, @matiaslauriti! I think I will let this alone as you suggest at this point.

Interesting question +1. My best shot is that it will use HTTP chunked encoding under the hood (PHP handles this, cf. flush()). If there is more abstraction in the response object for that (which likely does not make sense for production, but perhaps there is some test adapter), then look into that. If it splats out to stdout (in PHP CLI SAPI IIRC there is no HTTP chunking/flushing, and that is the SAPI PHPUnit is typically running in), then PHPUnit has output assertions. And if the library supports chunking, you don't have to test for chunks, only output. Rest is debugging IMHO.
